# Watch incoming queries with SQL Server 2008 r2

Tags: sql-server

I am running some tests with linq, how can I check what queries SQL Server is receiving?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use SQL Server Profiler

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929.aspx

Comment: i ended up downloading this profiler, http://code.google.com/p/sqlexpressprofiler/downloads/list, now what would be the next step? set up a trace?